# How to change ip to current url from subject in reset password email meteor

Tags: meteor, email-templates

I have used the following code to set my reset email subject:

```
Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.subject = function(user, url) {
    var ul = Meteor.absoluteUrl();

    var myArray = ul.split("//");
    var array = myArray[1].split('/');

    return "How to reset your password on "+array[0];
};
```

I want it to contain the current browser's url, but it's not happening.

This is what the subject looks like

> How to reset your password on 139.59.9.214

but the desired outcome is:

> How to reset your password on someName.com

where `someName.com` is my URL.

Comment: The email is sent from the server, not the client. The server is not aware of the current client's URL and it seems that you actually want the domain rather than the full URL. Do you plan on deploying your app to multiple domains?

Comment: @MasterAM No. I want that if I run that code  on localhost, then the email subject should look like 'How to reset your password on localhost:3000' and if I run my code after deployment it should be like 'How to reset your password on someName.com'.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend handling this a bit differently. Your host name is tied to your environment, and depending on what your production environment looks like, deriving your hostname from the server might not always be the easiest thing to do (especially if you're behind proxies, load balancers, etc.). You could instead look into leveraging Meteor's [Meteor.settings](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-settings) functionality, and create a settings file for each environment with a matching hostname setting. For example:

1) Create a `settings_local.json` file with the following contents:

```
{
  "private": {
    "hostname": "localhost:3000"
  }
}
```

2) Create a `settings.json` file with the following contents:

```
{
  "private": {
    "hostname": "somename.com"
  }
}
```

3) Adjust your code to look like:

```
Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.subject = function (user, url) {
  const hostname = Meteor.settings.private.hostname;
  return `How to reset your password on ${hostname}`;
};
```

4) When working locally, start meteor like:

```
meteor --settings=settings_local.json
```

5) When deploying to production, make sure the contents or your `settings.json` file are taken into consideration. How you do this depends on how you're deploying to your prod environment. If using [mup](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) for example, it will automatically look for a `settings.json` to use in production. MDG's [Galaxy](http://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/environment-variables.html) will do the same.